# How to extract the text in a SimpleXmlElement object?

Tags: php, simplexml

Consider the following code:

```
$div1 = new SimpleXmlElement("<div>hello,<strong>world</strong></div>");
echo $div1;//hello,
$div2 = new SimpleXmlElement("<div><strong>hello</strong>,world</div>");  
echo $div2;//,world
```

I want a method to get the whole text "hello,world", not just "hello," or ",world". How can I do?

Comment: Why are you using Simple XML when it seemst to be HTML?

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in method that returns the text of an element and its children all together. You'll need to write your own recursion and loops that concatenates them.